# change View design, React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

[image]

How can I sort the times in my view to be on a 'row' direction but each line should only contain 2 times,example :
*Lundi:               14:00  17:00

```
                   08:00  13:00
```

*Mercredi:           14:00  17:00,

```
                 08:00  18:00
```

here is a look at my code:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 5,marginLeft:100 }}>
  {
  lng.heure.length > 0 ?
  lng.heure.map((time, key) => <Text key={key} style={{ margin: 5 }}>
                                           {time}
                                </Text>)
                                    :
                                    <Text></Text>
                                }

                              </View>
```

i just map all the {times} of my array.
i really would appreciate your help.thank you

Comment: I think we'd need to see the actual data - not an image of it, but how it's actually being stored in your code. It could be 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional, an array of objects, etc., and that will affect the needed map code.

Comment: @tmdesigned ah ok, because the code is actually complicated. and i'm trying to get a solution just from the fact that i created an array "heure": [14:00,17:00.....  ] that contains times and i maped it.

Comment: You should provide the structure of the array, and are you using moment.js in your project ?